# C# WebClient.DownloadString(string) непредвиденная ошибка при передачи

Tags: c#, download

У меня все работает отлично без ошибок, а на другом пк - Ошибка при вызове web.DownloadString: "Базовое соединение закрыто. Непредвиденная ошибка при передачи". 
.net 4

что может быть и в какую сторону копать?

```
WebClient web = new WebClient { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
var doc = new HtmlDocument();

string page = web.DownloadString("https://www.somesite.com/somepage");
doc.LoadHtml(page);
```

Comment: Какой .Net? 4.5?

Comment: https поди не подключается.

Comment: @Geslot сборка на .net 4 была, у меня . net 4.5 на другом пк .net 4

Answer (score 4):

Судя по всему, дело в SecurityProtocol, которое использует Ваше приложение.
Дело в том, что как для версии 4.0 так и для версии 4.5 значение по-умолчанию `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` равно `SecurityProtocolType.Tls|SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3`. Тем не менее, .NET 4.0 поддерживает Tls до версии 1.0, в то время как .NET 4.5 поддерживает Tls до версии 1.2. Таким образом, Ваше приложение на компьютере с установленным .NET 4.5 будет иметь больше возможностей, нежели чем на компьютере с установленным .NET 4.0.
Я бы порекомендовал обновить .NET до версии 4.5 на обоих компьютерах, это должно разрешить проблему (желательно с предварительным удалением версии 4.0).

Comment: Нет возможности обновиться до 4.5 тк на другом пк установлена WinXP (ОС поменять тоже не представляется возможным)